# How to get min-height CSS property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, styles

As far as I was aware CSS properties of the DOM element `style` are camel-cased, such that `min-height` would be `element.style.minHeight`, but in my example below the style property is empty, but jQuery's abstraction gets it correctly.

```
// element with css: #test{ min-height: 100px; }
var el = document.getElementById('test');

console.log( el.style.minHeight );
// ""

console.log( $(el).css('min-height') );
// "100px"
```

[See fiddle for this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/VEuJe/).

What is jQuery doing to pull the correct style property that I'm not doing?

interestingly enough, adding a style attribute directly on the html element [does work](http://jsfiddle.net/VEuJe/2/).

Comment: looks like this is a case for `getComputedStyle`, but as the style is applied directly to the element and not inherited, I couldn't see why this would be required.

Comment: — The style property refers to inline style, not style sheets  (inherited or otherwise).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `window.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue("min-height")` and see if it returns the right value.

WARNING: It might not work on IE < 8.

From Mozilla's website...

CSS 2.0 defined only computed value as the last step in a property's calculation. Then, CSS 2.1 introduced the distinct definition of used value so that an element could explicitly inherit a width/height of a parent whose computed value is a percentage. For CSS properties that don't depend on layout (e.g. display, font-size, line-height), the computed values and used values are the same. These are the properties that do depend on layout so have a different computed value and used value: (taken from CSS 2.1 Changes: Specified, computed, and actual values):

background-position
bottom, left, right, top
height, width
margin-bottom, margin-left, margin-right, margin-top,
min-height, min-width
padding-bottom, padding-left, padding-right, padding-top
text-indent

Comment: Thanks yeh. I'm curious why computed style is required when the rule is applied directly to the element. Perhaps because it's a newer css standard?

Comment: Because it doesn't apply directly to the element. The style applies to all elements with the id of `test` However, while the style is applied to these elements, it's not *attached* to it. el.style will only get styles applied inline in the html. Any style applied elsewhere must be computed.

Comment: accepting as it best explains *why* computed style is required, not just that it should be used.

Comment: Works , thakns :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
style = window.getComputedStyle(el),
console.log( style.getPropertyValue('min-height'));
```

Check an update of your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VEuJe/4/

Comment: Cool!! trick, learn something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery method css is not so simple. You can check on this link [jquery css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> The .css() method is a convenient way to get a style property from the
>   first matched element, especially in light of the different ways
>   browsers access most of those properties (the getComputedStyle()
>   method in standards-based browsers versus the currentStyle and
>   runtimeStyle properties in Internet Explorer) and the different terms
>   browsers use for certain properties. For example, Internet Explorer's
>   DOM implementation refers to the float property as styleFloat, while
>   W3C standards-compliant browsers refer to it as cssFloat. For
>   consistency, you can simply use "float", and jQuery will translate it
>   to the correct value for each browser.